# Define a new handle (Similar to STDOUT)

Tags: batch-file, stdout, stdin

I was looking at redirecting handles in batch, when I noticed this:

[image: Table from wikipedia page]

Here is the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing))

It mentions that handles 3-9 are undefined and can be defined by a program. Now I've read about doing this in C#, but I wondered if this was possible in cmd/batch - and if it is, what are its limitations/use.

If it is not possible in cmd, how would I go about using this, and could it be a solution to outputting data to the screen and redirecting it to a file at the same time (a problem which has not been able to be done legitimately at the same time).

Thanks, Mona.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878007/how-to-permanently-redirect-standard-error-back-to-the-console-again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Batch file is limited to manage just two files: STDIN for input (SET /P) operations, and STDOUT for output (ECHO, etc.) operations; however, we could have access to more than one input and output files in a Batch file. How to do that? In a relatively easy way: just connect the additional files to unused handles (3-9) and use the appropiate handle in the input (SET /P <&#) or output (ECHO >&#) commands.

The Batch file below merge the lines of 3 input files into one output file with larger lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
3<input2.txt 4<input3.txt (
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input1.txt) do (
   set line=
   rem Read from input2.txt (and write line from input1 to output.txt):
   set /P line=%%a <&3
   rem Read from input3.txt (and write line from input2 to output.txt):
   set /P line=!line! <&4
   rem Write line from input3 to output.txt:
   echo(!line!
)
) >output.txt
```

The same method may be used to generate several output files.

See: [Access to SEVERAL files via Standard Handles](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3126)

And a more technical explanation [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2836&p=29634#p29634)

Comment: Actually, could I use this to output data to the console while accepting input?

Comment: Yes. Just use redirection to/from `CON`: `echo This always go to console > CON`

Comment: ...just in case "here" moves sometimes: [foolproof counting of arguments - Page 3 - DosTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2836&p=29634#p29634)

Comment: @Wolf: I am afraid I don't follow you... The posts at DosTips.com site are numbered and such numbers _never change_! In the case of the "here" link, the topic&reply numbers are `t=2836&p=29634#p29634` in both my answer and your comment, so your comment is totally unnecessary...