# How can I echo text from more files in a single line in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create something like a table in batch.
I have 2 files for example.

In first file named `names.txt` is typed:

```
John,
Emily,
```

And in second file named `numbers.txt` is typed:

```
78%,
89%,
```

Now I writed this, but I'm sure that is wrong:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=," %%A IN (names.txt,numbers.txt) DO (
ECHO. %%A have %%B.
PAUSE>NUL
```

I want to see this in console:

```
John have 78%.
Emily have 89%.
```

Is this possible? And if it is, how can I do that?

P.S.: I'm sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< numbers.txt (
   for /F "delims=," %%a in (names.txt) do (
      set /P number=
      echo %%a have !number:~0,-1!.
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I want to use 3 or more files, how can I do?

Comment: See: [Define a new handle (Similar to STDOUT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920517/define-a-new-handle-similar-to-stdout/19922932#19922932)