# batch script variable does NOT stay set

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-processing

I've run into a printer problem (0x2 error) when trying to install printers in the office.

The solution is to run the Win7 pnputil -e > oem_list.txt
Then remove all the oem*.inf files that are class 'Printers'
Run GPUpate /Force to refresh Group Policy and logoff.

When you login, no more error and you can install printers from the server.

Sample output from PNPUtil -e

```
Microsoft PnP Utility

Published name :            oem0.inf  
Driver package provider :   Microsoft  
Class :                     Printers  
Driver date and version :   06/21/2006 6.1.7600.16385  
Signer name :               Microsoft Windows   

Published name :            oem1.inf  
Driver package provider :   Famatech  
Class :                     Display adapters  
Driver date and version :   08/08/2007 3.1  
Signer name :               Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility   Publisher

Published name :            oem2.inf  
Driver package provider :   Intel Corporation  
Class :                     System devices  
Driver date and version :   11/02/2006 1.0.0.0   
Signer name :               Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility   Publisher

Published name :            oem3.inf  
Driver package provider :   Microsoft  
Class :                     Printers  
Driver date and version :   06/21/2006 6.1.7601.17514  
Signer name :               Microsoft Windows
```

I want to run "pnputil -f -d" on both oem0.inf and oem3.inf to remove them

I have tried several different BATCH loops using FOR /f and FINDSTR.
For example:

```
for /f "tokens=1,3,4" %%a IN (oem_list.txt) do (  
    if %%a==Published (  
       set save_it=%%c  
     ) else (  
    if %%b==Printers pnputil -f -d %save_it%)  
     )
```

However, even though save_it is set it is not -saved- by the time Class: Printers is found 2 lines down.

VERY Frustrating!

Please help!

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476) could explain the reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set statements don't appear to work in my batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177307/set-statements-dont-appear-to-work-in-my-batch-file)

Comment: Ok, that explains in more detail what I've already discovered. However, it does NOT explain how to MAKE IT WORK. :(  Surprising that something that is easy to code in C++ is so hard to do in a simple batch file.  And I do have a working PowerShell script that loads the lines into an array. However, not every PC here has PS installed and creating an array of 100's of lines seems so terribly inefficient.

Comment: This one gave me the idea of saving the output to a file  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484151/redirecting-output-from-within-batch-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
echo off
pnputil -e > oem_list.txt

for /f "tokens=1,3,4" %%a IN (oem_list.txt) do (
   if %%a==Published echo %%c > item.txt
   if %%b==Printers for /f %%a IN (item.txt) do (pnputil -f -d %%a))

DEL item.txt
DEL oem_list.txt
gpupdate /force /Logoff
```