# Redirected output from batch file using Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs when a `JButton` is clicked. The contents of the batch file is as follows:

```
@dsquery computer -name *%1

computerquery.bat FooUser > resultofbatch.txt
```

I'm having issues saving content to a txt file. The resultofbatch.txt gets created no problem, but it's blank and not saving the cmd prompt results to it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting Output from within Batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484151/redirecting-output-from-within-batch-file)

Comment: That's a post from 2013 from a different user. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes, that's the point. The question was already answered. I recommend the search function before posting.