# FINDSTR - get range of lines and text and put it to a file

Tags: batch-file, findstr

This command works fine - getting a range of lines and text

```
for /r %i in (*) do type %i|findstr/n ^^|findstr " ^30[6-9]: black blue
```

But the following command won't put the output to a file

```
for /r %i in (*) do type %i|findstr/n ^^|findstr " ^30[6-9]: black blue >>save.txt
```

What is the syntax that I need to use?

Comment: Related: [Redirecting Output from within Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484151/)

Comment: I've tried the command >output.text (for /r %i in (*) do type %i|findstr/n ^^|findstr " ^30[6-9]: black blue) and what comes up next is the text "more?"

Comment: And? what was the result?

Comment: press entter again and it just comes up with "more?' again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(@for /r %i in (*) do @type %i|findstr/n ^^|findstr " ^30[6-9]: black blue")>>x.txt
```

The search-strings need to be quoted - the end-quote is missing. The `@`s suppress the command-echo.

The enclosing parentheses are required if you use a single `>` as a redirector, which creates a new file. If you use `>>` then they are optional. Without them, each individual `findstr`'s output is appended to the file, which opens/closes the output file many times. WIth them, it's the `for` output that's redirected to the file.

Comment: Perfect... thanks so much :)