# how to output data to custom streams (3> 4> etc..) in windows console?

Tags: c++, windows, stream, console, stdout

In documentation there is info about additional streams besides standard *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr*. ( http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true )

`UNDEFINED 3-9 - These handles are defined individually by the application and are specific to each tool.`

So what I want to accomplish is to create by own output stream let's say on slot 3 and use it for debug. (I see there is no stddbg stream provided by the system.)

So my question is - Is it possible to check that a nonstandard output stream is waiting for data, like I do with stderr:

```
isatty(fileno(stderr)) == 0
```

And then I have option to choose a different kind of error information format more friendly to log file.
The code above is true when using command in this way:

```
myApp.exe param1 param2 2> error.log
```

but when I need to differentiate between debug (or performance) and error messages it's tempting to use another stream like:

```
myApp.exe param1 param2 3> debug.log
```

but how do I check that this stream is connected to the application, what name should I use as parameter to the `fileno()` function ?

Answer (score 2):

Handles 3-9 seem to be just additional temporary handles for playing with command line, for example for buffering some input/output. Look for some dos shell sorcerers' answers, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274145/686530) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888382/686530), to see how to use it. I don't think you can define it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the custom streams only exist within a particular instance of `cmd.exe` and are not passed to subprocesses.  (Even child `cmd.exe` processes don't inherit the custom streams from the parent.)

Comment: so the ms documentation is blatantly lying suggesting that these streams are programatically accessible: `specific to each tool`, wow.

Comment: Technically, they are programmatically accessible, but only to MS developers working on the built-in commands.  I suspect whoever wrote that document was either never aware of that limitation or didn't understand it.  Unfortunately, in my experience, the world is rather short on people who can both understand this sort of technical detail and can write about it clearly - many people can do one or the other, but few can do both. :-)